# How can I exclude a dynamic URL to show a popup created using 'Wordpress Popup' plugin

Tags: plugins, php, html

That might be a long shot, but I though I should give it a chance.

I am using [WordPress Popup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/) in order to show a popup when a user lands on specific pages on the website.
You create a popup and you can exclude it from showing up on specific URLs. I have a Deals website and I don't want the popup to show on cart's page. The problem I'm facing is that the page has a dynamic URL and it looks like this: 'http://domain.com/cart/?add_to_cart=329'

I have tried the following ways to write it down:

1. http://domain.gr/cart/
2. http://domain.gr/cart/?add_to_cart=/
3. http://domain.gr/cart/?add_to_cart=%/
4. http://domain.gr/cart/?add_to_cart=?/
5. http://domain.gr/cart/?add_to_cart/

Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm desperated here! :)

Kat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the javascript file the developer calls a method when the page loads.

```
jQuery(window).load(po_selectiveLoad);
```

This methods calls another method.

```
function po_selectiveLoad() {       
    po_load_popover();
}
```

If you replace it with this

```
function po_selectiveLoad() {
        var urlString = new String(window.location.href);
        if (!urlString.match(/\/cart\//)) {
            po_load_popover();
        }
    }
```

Of course this is not good because you will need to modify the plugin files.

I am not sure if the developer has provided the option of preventing a pop up based on a phrase or word contained within the url, i installed the plugin and did not see an option.

It may be a feature of the plugin the developer will implement at a later date or you can ask. Hope this helps.

Comment: that did it! Thank u!
BTW I don't see any option in the plugin to prevent the popup from showing based on a phrase or a word. I guess it would be a good idea to suggest it to the developer.
Thank u again for the help!